# Angular 6 ngFor count before slice pipe

Tags: angular

I have an *ngFor with both custom pipes and the standard slice pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let offer of offerListData | slice:0:propertyLimit | offerFilter: countyId: cityId as filtered; let i = index; let propCount = count"><p>Offer id = {{offer.Id}}</p></div>
```

This workes fine, but is it possible to get the length of the offerListData before the slice pipe has kicked in?

The result I hope for is:

Offer count = 4

Offer id = 1

Offer id = 2

Offer id = 3

Offer id = 4

Should I pass the counter from my pipe to the component, if so, how?

EDIT:

Thanks to @JB Nizet I see that my question is verry confusing, so I try to clearify what I want

In my *ngFor I have a custom pipe called offerListData where I list my offers after filtering for county and city

I want to only display the first 5 of the offers and have a button to load the rest (I have already fixed this function)

To manage that I use the default slice pipe

The problem is that I want to display how many offers I got after my custom pipe, and not after the slice pipe

If I use this I get the total number of offers, before my custom pipe:
offerListData.length

And if I use filtered.length I only get the number of offers after both my custom pipe and the slice pipe

What i really want is to display the total number of offers after my custom pipe.
Prefered is something like this:

```
<p>Total number of offers: 4</p>
<div *ngFor="let offer of offerListData | slice:0:propertyLimit | offerFilter: countyId: cityId as filtered;">
    <p>Offer id = {{offer.Id}}</p>
</div>
```

Would it be better to set a "count" parameter in the pipe to be used in "Total number of offers"? Is it even possible to send a parameter from the pipe to the view or the component?

EDIT 2:
I found a fix, don't know if it's be best way, but this works:

I added a div element outside my ngFor, with id offerCounter

And in the pipe I used this:

```
document.getElementById('offerCounter').innerHTML = this.resultFromFilter.length.toString();
```

Comment: offerListData.length?

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, if I use offerListData.length I just get the count before the custom pipe

Comment: No, you don't. offerListData.length is the length of offerListData. The slice pipe doesn't modify the array. It creates a sliced copy of the array.

Comment: You are rigth that the offerListData don't change according to the slice pipe, but it remains the same after the offerFilter pipe, what I want it to know is the length after the offerFilter pipe, but before the slice pipe

Comment: You are first piping with _slice_ then piping with _offerFilter_ , so at which point do you want to have the count ? After _slice_ , of after _offerFilter_ ?

Comment: If it's possble I would like to have the length after the offerFilter

Comment: Then it will also be after the slice pipe, since the array is first sliced, then passes through offerFilter. You understand that, right? Because you're constantly contradicting yourself until now. If that's what you want, `filtered.length` is whet you want.